# customize error page 404 in jdeveloper

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I create a new jsf page for showing errors like 404 and put it in web.xml  element.
When I open page directly like : localhost/error.jsf , everything show correctly, but try to navigate to :localhost/sdsddssd (for 404 error test) , error.jsf file shows like a xml file!

Comment: Your url pattern is probably `<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>` so sdsdsds doesn't have `.jsf` that's why it is not processed by the servlet.

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie : tried sdsddssd.jsf too! same result

Answer (score 0):

Could you try changing your jsf file to a jspx file. As well as make sure the reference to the error page is changed to jspx?

I think when the error.jsf page loads it is not meant to read xml unless it is being included on a jspx page. A jspx page is meant to handle xml within it.